# Is there any way to have Rust add the SDL2 iOS libraries to my own library?

Tags: ios, rust, sdl-2

I have a small project made with Rust that uses rust-sdl2 to manage windows, graphics, etc... It's pretty simple as it only displays a window and clears it.

It works fine on macOS and I'm trying to make it work on iOS as well. I managed to compile the library for the simulator using `cargo build --no-default-features --target x86_64-apple-ios --lib` and I can see both the dylib and .a being generated.

I created a new iOS project in Xcode and added the library to the project. I also made sure to mark the function that I want to call with `#[no_mangle]` and added the `extern "C"` prefix.

I did something similar in the main view controller (I know it's the wrong place as I should actually replace the main.m file and let SDL2 manage the whole application lifecycle, but I'll get there later):

```c
extern void run_loop();

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  run_loop();
}
```

I also added the path to the generated library to the project's libraries search path.

When I compile it everything is fine, but the linker is complaining that it can't find the SDL2 libraries. That makes sense as I'm not including the iOS version of those libraries. The point is, is there any way to have Rust add the SDL2 iOS libraries inside my own library so that I do not need to carry around more dependencies or should I compile the iOS version of SDL2 by hand and add them to the project?

Comment: Hopefully someone will answer your question on here, but if they don't, make sure to check out the rust_gamedev Reddit and IRC - I know for a fact there's at least one person on there who has shipped an iOS game written in Rust and SDL.